# Why parallel_iterations in dynamic_rnn doesn't work?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm wondering how to use the dynamic_rnn function and make it parallel. I set `gpu_options.allow_growth = True` and use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False, parallel_iterations=50)` to do so. But both the GPU memory consumption and run time don't change when I changeing the value of `parallel_iterations`.

It is a very simple rnn, so I think there may not be data dependency.

```
basic_cell = BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32, parallel_iterations=50)
logits = fully_connected(states, n_outputs, activation_fn=None)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
```

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations don't mean that `parallel_iterations` don't work.

Whenever you have an RNN, you have a data dependency since the output of n'th step is fed into (n+1)'th step. In your example with `BasicRNNCell`, every computation is effectively dependent on previous computation. So, there are basically no opportunities to run multiple steps in parallel. With more complex cells you might have some computation in each step that is independent of previous steps (e.g. doing some attention over constant memory). In such cases there are opportunities for parallel execution of different steps.

Even if you model would allow for parallel execution, you might not be able to see it being reflected in memory usage. Memory usage depends on many factors including when TF returns memory to GPU; if you are computing gradients, you might need to keep most activations in memory whether you run iterations in parallel or not; the   iterations that are run in parallel might not produce a lot of tensors; etc.

Similarly for CPU, if running stuff in parallel always helped performance, we would run a thousand threads in every process. `parallel_iterations` is simply a knob that is useful to have in some cases.